# SQL Get Rows with given value or rows that are the closest to the value

Tags: sql-server

I need to get from a query the rows with the value equal to a parameter or the one that are the closed based on ID.

```
ID          Value
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           2
3           1

CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int, Value int)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3,1)
```

So for a value = 3 it should return

```
ID          Value
----------- -----------
1           3
2           2
3           1
```

Becouse for ID = 1 we have Value 3, and for the other I want the value that is the closest to my given input 3.

Edit:

So for value = 2 it should return

```
ID          Value
----------- -----------
1           2
2           2
3           1
```

Comment: Why would it return ID=2,Value=2 but not ID=1,Value=2? How is (2,2) *closer* to 3 than (1,2)?

Comment: For each ID i have a number of values ( 1,2,3,4,5). For each ID i want to get only one row, based on the input i give. If I can't find that input ( input is bigger then values for that specific ID i want the on that is closest to it ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY` on the `ID` to group the sets of data and use `MAX` to take the highest value, and limit the data use your supplied value in a `WHERE` clause like so:

```
DECLARE @val INT = 3

CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int, Value int)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3,1) 

SELECT  ID ,
        MAX(Value)
FROM    #Test
WHERE   Value <= @val
GROUP BY ID

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: It does solve part of my problem that I could give out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This allows returning data fields other than ID and Value which is a restriction when using group by.

```
 Declare @Param Int = 2

    ;With cteAssigned As
    (
    Select ID, Value, 
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By ID Order By Value Desc) SortOrder
        From #Test
        Where Value <= @Param
    )
    Select * From cteAssigned Where SortOrder = 1
```

EDIT Without CTE
Declare @Param Int = 2

```
Select * 
    From
        (
        Select ID, Value, 
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By ID Order By Value Desc) SortOrder
            From #Test
            Where Value <= @Param
        ) A
    Where SortOrder = 1
```

Comment: Can't really use CTE as my "table" is already a CTE table. But thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, i've found my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ID ,MAX(VALUE) VALUE FROM #TEST
    GROUP BY ID

DECLARE @ID INT = 3
SELECT ID ,MAX(VALUE) VALUE FROM #TEST
 WHERE ID <= @ID
GROUP BY ID

then this is also correct only
```

Comment: This will always the max(value) i want the value that equals to my paramter or the one that is closest to that, check my edit for input = 2

Comment: I think this isnt he is asking. I think the example he gave; isnt that good.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int, Value int)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3,1) 

DECLARE @Value INT = 0

SELECT DISTINCT
       t.ID,
       ca_t.Value
FROM #Test t
CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP 1 t2.Value
      FROM #Test t2
      WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
      ORDER BY ABS(t2.Value - @Value)
    ) ca_t
```

So just change the @Value to what ever value you're looking for.